# Гласные после шипящих

Tags: орфография

Почему слово "чечётка" пишется через "ё"? Каким словом можно проверить?

Comment: Тот же вопрос касательно слова "чётко".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Почему "чечётка" через"ё"? Каким словом можно проверить?
>
> Тот же вопрос касательно слова "чётко".

Можно воспользоваться [правилом](http://orthographia.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=7452#pp7452):

> **§ 19.** Во всех остальных случаях для передачи ударного гласного ***о*** после ***ж, ч, ш, щ*** пишется буква ***ё***, а именно:
>
> <…>
>
> **7.** В тех корнях русских слов, где ударному звуку ***о*** соответствует в других однокоренных словах или формах гласный (**ударный**
>   **или безударный**), передаваемый буквой ***е***…
>
> ***чёткий, чёткость, отчётливый*** (***четкА*** -- кр. ф. жен. р.)
>
> ***чечётка (чЕчет).***

**P.S.**

***ЧЁТКИЙ*** исторически связано с ***(про)честь, чтение***.

Answer (score 2):

**ЧЕЧЁТКА**.  **Чёткий по ритму**, быстрый танец с частым и дробным пристукиванием подошвы и каблука об пол.

**ЧЁТКИЙ**, 1. Отчётливый, ясно членимый (о движениях). Ч. шаг. 2. Хорошо видимый, различимый во всех подробностях, частностях; отчётливый.  Разборчивый, легко читаемый (о почерке, графическом изображении). Ч-ая надпись. Напечатать чётким типографским шрифтом.

Итак, **чёткий** - это тот, который легко можно прочесть. Корень ЧЕТ/ЧЁТ со значением работы с информацией, восприятия информации **относится к корням с историческим чередованием Е/Ё** (сравнить: чёрный/чернеть, чем/ в чём, пчела/пчёлы), в которых пишется гласная Ё.